# how to fix npm/ yeoman installation error: TypeError: cannot read property 'proxy' of undefined

Tags: windows, npm, yeoman, git-bash

I am currently trying to install the yeoman generator for a MEAN stack project I'm starting, and I don't understand where I'm messing up/ if it's me or a machine error. when the install process hits the sanity checks, it has some sort of proxy detection error as it is looking for a proxy in a folder that doesn't exist. any ideas as to what is going on?

I've properly set the npm config proxies, and I've followed the yeoman tutorial for setup on their website.

```
//I ran: npm install --global yo 
//cut to the part where it messed up, there's a lot here 
//'...' is where my userID is 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'proxy' of undefined
     at new OuterHttpAgent 
(C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\global- 
tunnel-ng\lib\agents.js:17:28)
 × yo version
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'proxy' of undefined
    at new OuterHttpAgent 
(C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\global- 
tunnel-ng\lib\agents.js:17:28)
```

the file path ceases to be valid after it reaches the node modules (Ex: the first nonexistent file in the folder is \yo... ) folder. I went in with the windows file explorer and couldn't find anything below that. is this an issue within the actual yeoman code, or do I need to change something on my end for the files to properly generate? I have had no issue installing other plugins like express.js, oracledb, and I even successfully installed yeoman a while ago and didn't have this issue, so I'm wondering what could have changed.